# Finding the next term in the sequence: $2028, 4624, 6498, 11638$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

What is the logic deployed in this sequence: **2028, 4624, 6498, 11638**

What will be the next term in this sequence?

Comment: [One possible answer](https://oeis.org/search?q=+2028%2C+4624%2C+6498%2C+11638&language=english&go=Search) is $23548$

Comment: Check https://oeis.org/search?q=2028%2C%204624%2C%206498%2C%2011638&language=english&go=Search[/link]. From there you can find the following terms, a formula behind the sequence and much more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most obvious thing to do when identifying a sequence is to search on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) (The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences). [OEIS suggests one sequence](https://oeis.org/search?q=+2028%2C+4624%2C+6498%2C+11638&language=english&go=Search), that is:
$$a_n=p_n^3-p_n^2$$
Where $p_n$ denotes the $n$-th prime number. In your case, the sequence will start from $n=6$ (i.e $p_6=13$).
This sequence would imply that the next term would be $a_{10}=23548$, as mentioned by @lioness99a.

---

However, note that given an finite subsequence, there are an infinite number of possible sequences which contain that subsequence. For example, using an [interpolating polynomial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolatingpolynomial(2028,4624,6498,11638)), we find that the following sequence is also perfectly valid:
$$a_n=\frac{1994 n^3}{3} - 4349 n^2 + \frac{32971 n}{3} - 5278$$
This would imply that the next term is $a_5=24032$.

Comment: The next term could be any number because we can always find a corresponding rule. This is clear when a sequence is considered as a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \ \mathbb{R}$.